# How can I get token from Stripe payment in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I'm doing Stripe payment method for the first time and the Api developer told me to give him token for Stripe payment. I've seen tutorial about it but couldn't find about token from anywhere. I also have implemented it and success the payment but need to find the token.

Here is how I was trying to do but getting error:

```
Future<void> makePayment() async {
    try {
      paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent("20", "USD");
      if (paymentIntent == null) {
        // handle the error
        print("Error creating payment intent");
        return;
      }
      await Stripe.instance
          .initPaymentSheet(
              paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
                  paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent?['client_secret'],
                  // applePay: PaymentSheetApplePay(merchantCountryCode: "+971"),
                  // googlePay: PaymentSheetGooglePay(testEnv: true, currencyCode: "AE"),
                  style: ThemeMode.dark,
                  merchantDisplayName: "Marketingo"))
          .then((value) {});
      displayPaymentSheet();
      var tokenData = await Stripe.instance.createToken(params);
      if (tokenData.tokenId != null) {
        var token = tokenData.tokenId;
        // Use the token to complete the payment on your server.
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("exception $e");
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your API developer trying to do with that token? which parameter in the Stripe API is he trying to pass that `token` into? the term `token` is fairly vague.

Comment: We want to implement token in our app he and told me that give me token for stripe payment. so, I'm figuring it out how can  i get this. as i have successfully impalement stripe but can't find token anywhere.

Comment: Nothing about what you've just mentioned provides the information that the community needs to help you. Can you ask the API developer to provide exact URL to the Stripe API docs for the request and specify which specific API parameter he needs that token for? e.g. is he trying to pass the `token` into https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method? Otherwise, what does he need that token for?

Comment: I've added code. kindly check

Comment: Again, it's still not entirely clear what you require that token for. Without knowing what Stripe API you're trying to call on the **backend** with that token and which parameter you need that token for, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: For context, since you're using a PaymentIntent, the payment is typically confirmed and completed on the frontend. So there should be no need to "complete" the payment in your server. There are exceptions, for example, if your PaymentIntent was created with `capture_method=manual` or `confirmation_method=manual`. However, in both of these cases, you would typically need the PaymentIntent id, not the PaymentMethod.

Comment: If your backend developer needs the PaymentIntent id, or the PaymentMethod id from the successful PaymentIntent to write to the database asynchronously, then they should use webhooks and listen for the `payment_intent.succeeded` event : https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: Also, card Tokens (assuming that's what you're referring to) have been deprecated. You would want to look at / use PaymentMethods instead.